# T-SQL, possibly combining MAX and BETWEEN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following excerpt from an SQL Query in SQL Server:

```
 LEFT JOIN tbl_StuAssess SA (NOLOCK)
     ON CA.ASMT_PK = SA.ASMT_PK
        AND SA.DELT_FLAG = 0
        AND CA.SCRE_MTOD_PK = SA.SCRE_MTOD_PK
        AND CVS.STUD_PK = SA.STUD_PK
        AND(SA.ASMT_DATE BETWEEN @YearStartDate AND @YearEndDate)
```

Here is my issue, If the first 4 conditions I met, I want the last condition `(SA.ASMT_DATE BETWEEN @YearStartDate AND @YearEndDate)` to only return the Latest date that is in between `@YearStartDate` and `@YearEndDate` and that meets all the other conditions. Can anyone tell me how I can do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Where is the SELECT statement?

Comment: What's the rest of the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do possibly do this with a subquery:

```
LEFT JOIN
(select sa.*,
        row_number() over (partition by asmt_pk, scre_mtod_pk, stud_pk order by asmt_dt desc) as seqnum
 from tbl_StuAssess SA (NOLOCK)
 where SA.DELT_FLAG = 0 and (SA.ASMT_DATE BETWEEN @YearStartDate AND @YearEndDate))
) sa
ON CA.ASMT_PK = SA.ASMT_PK and
   CA.SCRE_MTOD_PK = SA.SCRE_MTOD_PK and
   CVS.STUD_PK = SA.STUD_PK and
   sa.seqnum = 1
```

This calculates the last date before the join.  This works, if the join conditions are not filtering out some but not all of the records for a given group of `asmt_pk, scre_mtod_pk, stud_pk`.

The alternative is to use `row_number()` at the next higher level.  Same idea, but without the rest of the code, I can't provide a code sample.